# Como obtener con javascript el valor de un atributo y cambiarlo

Tags: javascript

Tengo las siguientes etiquetas

```
<a href="#" onclick="mostrarContrasena()">
   <span  id="lg" data-feather="eye"></span>
</a>
```

como se muestra dentro de la etiqueta a tengo un span y quisiera poder cambiar el valor del atributo data-feader dentro de la función MonstrarContrasena pero no logro detectar el elemento

```
    function mostrarContrasena(){
      var tipo = document.getElementById("clave");
      if(tipo.type == "password"){
          tipo.type = "text";
      }else{
          tipo.type = "password";
      }
      // var div1 = document.getElementById("atributo");
  var align = document.getElementById('lg').getAttribute('data-feather');
      
  }
```

al hacer un console.log me muestra null

Comment: has probado con `document.getElementById('lg').setAttribute("data-feather", "valor");`?

Comment: Tu código funciona bien. Pero donde está tu input?

Comment: Si, funciona bien... miralo aqui mismo: https://jsfiddle.net/x34boz0y/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que esto te sea de ayuda :).

Intenta evitar los onclick como atributo en alguna etiqueta (es un mal uso).

Para ver mejor el resultado, tienes que verlo en pantalla completa.

```js
var botonMostrar = document.getElementById("showPassword"); // botón para mostrar y ocultar contraseña
var password = document.getElementById("password"); // input password
var bool = true; // boleano
botonMostrar.onclick = () => { // dar función al botón mostrar

  if (bool) {
    botonMostrar.innerText = "ocultar"; // cambiar el texto del botón
    password.setAttribute("type", "text"); // cambiar atributo del input para mostrar contraseña
    bool = false;
  } else {
    botonMostrar.innerText = "mostrar";
    password.setAttribute("type", "password"); // ocultamos la contraseña
    bool = true; // cambiamos el boleano a true
  }

};
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(111, 145, 220);
  position: relative;
}

form {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
  border-radius: 11px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(118, 118, 118, 0.796);
  position: relative;
}

form h3 {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

form div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

form div input {
  width: 250px;
  height: 38px;
  border: none;
  margin: 17px 0px;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4444;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

form div button {
  right: 28px;
  bottom: 44px;
  width: 55px;
  height: 30px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 13.6px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  color: rgb(91, 118, 177);
}

form #enviar {
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  background: rgb(17, 17, 17);
  color: white;
  font-size: 17.5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(-51%);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
  <form id="formulario">
    <h3>Show Password</h3>
    <div class="password">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" autocomplete="off" />
      <input id="password" type="password" name="contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña" autocomplete="off" />
      <button id="showPassword" type="button">mostrar</button>
    </div>
    <input id="enviar" type="button" value="Enviar" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias de verdad

Comment: @Enrique no hay de que :).

Answer (score 0):

El código de la pregunta funciona bien, aunque podría ser el `input`, lo que no está, que le falte el **ID**.

```html
<input type="password" id="clave">
  
<a href="#" onclick="mostrarContrasena()"> 
 <span id="lg" data-feather="eye">Botón</span> 
</a>


<script>
function mostrarContrasena(){ 
var tipo = document.getElementById("clave"); 

if(tipo.type == "password"){ 
tipo.type = "text"; 

}else{
 tipo.type = "password"; 
}

// var div1 = document.getElementById("atributo"); 
var align = document.getElementById('lg').getAttribute('data-feather'); }
</script>
```